# Moving an email into a folder - checking in alphabetical folders if already exists and if not create new folder then drop contents in

Tags: vba, outlook

Pretty new to vba but created the following code which creates a new folder if it can't find it in the alphabetical files already. The folder structure is A-Z and in the example you can see I managed to get it to create the folder but it didn't check in the 'P' folder to see if it already existed - I stuck a file in 'P Folder' called 'Person Test 12345678', it should have added it in there but it didn't look in 'P folder'. What am I doing wrong with my code?

```
Sub MoveEmailsToHardDriveFolder()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNs As Object
    Dim olInbox As Object
    Dim subFolder As Object
    Dim olItems As Object
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim subjectKeyword As String
    Dim hardDrivePath As String
    Dim subfolderPath As String
    Dim filePath As String

    ' Set the keyword to identify emails to be moved based on the subject
    subjectKeyword = "PSAmend"

    ' Set the root path of the hard drive folder where you want to move the emails
    hardDrivePath = "\\nch\dfs\SharedArea\HR\HR-PC\Employee Files\CURRENT STAFF\"

    ' Create Outlook Application and Namespace objects
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Set the Inbox folder
    Set olInbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 corresponds to the Inbox folder, change it if needed

    ' Set the subfolder within the Inbox (adjust the subfolder name as needed)
    Set subFolder = olInbox.Folders("Contracts")

    ' Set the Items collection in the subfolder
    Set olItems = subFolder.Items

    ' Loop through each email in the subfolder
    ' On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling
    For Each olItem In olItems
        ' Check if the subject contains the specified keyword
        If InStr(1, olItem.Subject, subjectKeyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Get the subject as the subfolder name
            subfolderPath = Replace(olItem.Subject, ":", "_")

            ' Use the subject and subfolder as the file path
            filePath = hardDrivePath & subfolderPath & "\" & Replace(olItem.Subject, ":", "_") & ".msg"

            ' Create the subfolder if it doesn't exist
            If Dir(hardDrivePath & subfolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                MkDir hardDrivePath & subfolderPath
            End If

            ' Save the email as a .msg file to the specified path
            olItem.SaveAs filePath, 3 ' 3 corresponds to olMSG format

            ' Move the email to the specified destination folder (optional)
            ' olItem.Move destFolder
        End If
    Next olItem
    ' On Error GoTo 0 ' Disable error handling

    ' Clean up objects
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set subFolder = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I stuck a file in 'P Folder' call 'Person Test 12345678', it should have added it in there but it didn't look in 'P folder'. What am I doing wrong with my code:

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is ignoring any errors which might be occurring - comment that out and see what happens.

Comment: How do you know "P" is not checked? `On Error Resume Next` is a poor way to handle unexpected errors. As already advised, comment it and debug. What error message is triggered?

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for looking at this for me, I commented out both of the error handling parts but it is still creating a folder outside of 'P' where the folder called Person Test exists. All it does is create a new folder but underneath 'P' not inside of 'P', hopefully thanks makes sense

Comment: I edited code above so you can see where I am at now. It does generate a new folder but its a the same level as 'P' not inside the 'P' folder, which means it still hasn't looked for the existing folder inside 'P'.

Comment: Looks like you need to determine the first character of the keyword then insert a folder named that character between hardDrivePath and subfolderPath.

Answer (score 0):

Add the alphabetic folder to the end of `hardDrivePath`.

```vb
Dim subfolderAlpha As String
subfolderAlpha = UCase(Left(subjectKeyword, 1)) & "\"
hardDrivePath = hardDrivePath & subfolderAlpha
```